# what is web method attribute in web service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, webmethod

what is web method attribute in web service? fro example

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public string GetApplicationDomains(string strParameterList)
{

}
```

for what purpose this attributes WebMethod and ScriptMethod are used?

Comment: similar one here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941484/webmethod-vs-scriptmethod

Comment: A note: all of these attributes are used with ASMX web services. Microsoft has recently stated that ASMX web service technology is a legacy technology, and has stated that they will not be fixing bugs in that code.

Answer (score 7):

[WebMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx(VS.71).aspx) indicates "the method exposed as part of the XML Web service."
[ScriptMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptmethodattribute.aspx) "Specifies which HTTP verb is used to invoke a method, and the format of the response"

Answer (score 1):

**WebMethod** attribute identifies this method as a web service method.

The **ScriptMethodAttribute** attribute is optional.

If a method is not marked with **ScriptMethodAttribute**, the method will be called by using the HTTP POST command and the response will be serialized as JSON. You cannot override this setting from script.

Answer (score 1):

The [WebMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.webmethodattribute%28VS.71%29.aspx) attribute enables the method to be called through the web service.

The [ScriptMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptmethodattribute.aspx) attribute tells which method should be used to call the method (POST/GET) and with formatting the response should use (JSON or XML)