# What is the difference between [HttpPost] and [WebMethod]?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

What are the main differences in functionality between these two method attributes?

Comment: @SajadLfc Yea, but couldn't find exactly what I was looking for. This question has not been asked before on this site, and possible duplicate you posted isn't what I'm asking. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[HttpPost]` is an Attribute that decorates a controller or controller action in ASP.Net MVC. You will use it to  only allow a request to enter this action method if it is of type "POST".

It looks like this typically:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyControllerAction()
{
  // only can get here if httprequest was a "POST"
}
```

A `[WebMethod]` attribute is used to decorate methods on an old school .asmx page typically used for making a web service. Attaching the `[WebMethod]` attribute to a Public method indicates that you want the method exposed as part of the XML Web service.

Typically looks like this on an .asmx page:

```
public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{ 
    [WebMethod] // exposes XML Web Service Method
    public DataSet IAmAWebServiceMethod()
    {
       //implementation code
    }
}
```

They are not comparable and do completely different operations. One handles "POST" requests for a web application while another exposes a XML Web Service method.

Answer (score 1):

There is no comparison between them. `[WebMethod]` is part of the legacy ASMX web service technology and should not be used for new development.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are plenty of discussions already going on these topics
They are entirely different please check these links for a basic idea of both

[HttpPost vs HttpGet attributes in MVC: Why use HttpPost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332275/httppost-vs-httpget-attributes-in-mvc-why-use-httppost)

[what is web method attribute in web service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243382/what-is-web-method-attribute-in-web-service)