# Why does WebMethod in .aspx page ignore DataContract - DataMember attributes

Tags: asp.net-3.5, webmethod

When I send back a Class, it ignores the DataContract - DataMember attributes and serializes all members of the class as well as sends the class name in the "__type" flag as well.  How can I make it respect the DataMember attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebMethods use the legacy "ASMX Web Service" technology. DataContract is part of WCF.

They are totally unrelated technologies.

Comment: Which is preferred now, ScriptMethod or WebMethod?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941484/webmethod-vs-scriptmethod answers my question.