# WebMethod Not getting called from Jquery in asp.net

Tags: jquery, webmethod

I tried to make a call from jquery to asp.net webmethod.But it never get invoked from Jquery.

```
[WebMethod]
public void AddProductToCart(int productid)
{
   Response.Write(productid.ToString());
   MyShoppingCart usersShoppingCart = new MyShoppingCart();
   String cartId = usersShoppingCart.GetShoppingCartId();
   try
   {
       usersShoppingCart.AddItem(cartId, productid, 1);
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       throw new Exception(ex.Message);
   }
```

Jquery function

```
function d(t) {
        e.ajax({
        url: "productmodel.aspx/AddProductToCart",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(t),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        sucess: function () {
            alert("added to cart successfully");
        }
    })
}
```

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: What happens? Check your console, specifically the network tab, what is the status of the request? We need more info!

Comment: I guess Webmethods should be static in .aspx.cs files, may be you are getting 404 not found exception in your console tab

Comment: Use [ScriptMethod Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptmethodattribute(v=vs.110).aspx). See [WebMethod vs ScriptMethod](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941484/webmethod-vs-scriptmethod), and the method must be `public static`

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan missed static and messed up... thanks

Answer (score 5):

ASP.NET Webmethods must be static methods.

Change your declaration to :

```
[WebMethod]
public static void AddProductToCart(int productid)
{
    ...
```