# Jquery ajax success call but web method breakpoint not hit

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I have a simple set up.

Jquery:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "/MyApp/MyHandler.ashx/MyMethod",
  success: function(result) {
    alert("sucess");
  },
  error: function() {
    alert('Error');
  }
});
```

and web method:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static void MyMethod(){
  new AnotherClass(null).AnotherMethod(null, null); 
}
```

problem is success alert is called but break point is not hit inside `MyMethod`.

Comment: you have to mention the Http methods . like type : "Get",

Comment: console `result` instead of alerting "success".

Comment: Did you try to place `[HttpGet]` attribute on web method?

Comment: Try to disable `JQuery` `AJAX` caching  `$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });`

Comment: @KovalenkoIvan can you please elaborate why I need that?

Comment: @Anonymous Sorry, I've mistaken. You should use `[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]` instead `[HttpGet]`. `[HttpGet]` is from MVC. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941484/webmethod-vs-scriptmethod) are good answers why.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and this is what I ended up having to do:

```
$.ajax({
   url: _url,
   data: '',
   dataType: 'json',
   contentType: 'application/json',
   type: 'POST',
   success: function(result) {
      alert("sucess");
   },
   error: function() {
      alert('Error');
   }
});
```

My first attempt left out the `data`, `dataType` and `contentType`; Only when I set `contentType: 'application/json'` with an empty string (`data: ''`) did it end up working. What a headache - hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was in RoutingConfig.So, sort that in App_Start folder, within RouteConfig,commented out the following line

//settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;